# android how to add byte[] data to cloud firestore database

Tags: android, database, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried to upload my data of local database to Cloud Firestore database, and the data type of one field is byte[]. It can't be success or failure.

```
        Map<String, Object> setDetail = new HashMap<>();
        j = cursor.getColumnIndex("sound");
        byte[] sound = cursor.getBlob(j);
        setDetail.put("sound", sound);
        dbFire.collection("SetDetails").document(strWordID).set(setDetail)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    }
                });
```

The debugger steps over this line **dbFire.collection("SetDetails").document(strWordID).set(setDetail)**

then jumps out to the last line of **zzj.class**

```
final class zzj implements Runnable {
zzj(zzi var1, Task var2) {
    this.zzm = var1;
    this.zzg = var2;
}

public final void run() {
    synchronized(zzi.zza(this.zzm)) {
        if (zzi.zzb(this.zzm) != null) {
            zzi.zzb(this.zzm).onComplete(this.zzg);
        }

    }
}
```

}

If I continue running, it will jump to this line of **Looper.java**

```
        final int thresholdOverride =
            SystemProperties.getInt("log.looper."
                    + Process.myUid() + "."
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + ".slow", 0);
```

I have read documents, **Bytes** is one of data types that Cloud Firestore supports, so what's wrong with it. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to log the exception, what does it say?

Comment: @AlexMamo Could not serialize object. Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead (found in field 'sound')

Comment: So it's very clear, right? You should change the type from array to list.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it.

Comment: Ok and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write a byte array type field on Android, use [Blob.fromBytes()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Blob#fromBytes%28byte[]%29) to convert a byte array to a Blob object, then provide the Blob object to `update()` or `set()`.